# How to remove map route for HERE map API

Tags: javascript, here-api

I currently have a function drawing a map line when clicking on an option, however I only want one to be displayed at a time, so that when the user clicks on another option, it erases the previously drawn route, then draws a new one. I've tried to research how to do this but have come up with nothing.

```
function addRouteShapeToMap(route) {
  route.sections.forEach((section) => {
    let linestring = H.geo.LineString.fromFlexiblePolyline(section.polyline);
    let polyline = new H.map.Polyline(linestring, {
      style: {
        lineWidth: 8,
        strokeColor: "rgba(207, 0, 15, 1)",
      },
    });

    map.addObject(polyline);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove the polyline, or generally any added map object, with the method *removeObject*. This assumes you keep a reference to the polyline outside the function which adds it to the map, or else you could iterate over map objects retrieved with *map.getObjects* to find it.

```
map.removeObject(polyline);
```

See the [API Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.25.0/api_reference/H.Map.html#removeObject)